# How to prevent Visual Studio from generating staticwebassets.runtime.json?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I don't know what the staticwebassets.runtime.json file does, but it's not needed on my production site, and not published by Visual Studio. Is there a way to prevent this file from being generated?

Comment: Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using. 
If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.
show us some code that you've tried and explain how generating staticwebassets.runtime.json  and we'll be better able to help you.